# Retain fixtures with multiple adapters per Ember environment

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Although the natural progression would [replace the fixture adapter with another adapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/), I'd like to retain fixtures for development environment while leveraging a different Ember data adapter for production.

This is due to:

- Heavy iterations of progressive enhancement
- Intended to run embedded in a UIWebView from an iOS app, production configuration is tightly coupled with bridged calls to native assembly for data.

[Ember CLI](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) asset compilation is based on [broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli) to load either a Web or Native API:

```
app.import({
    development: 'vendor/company/WebAPI.js',
    production: 'vendor/company/NativeAPI.js'
});
```

However, I'm unsure how to leverage this pattern to change adapters.

#### Development Environment

For development, I want to use mock data or http services to enable testing in browser.

Therefore, launching Ember server in development environment leverages fixtures.

```
ember server --environment=development
```

This configuration would extend [FixtureAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.FixtureAdapter.html) for development:

```
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    /* ... */
});
export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

#### Production Environment

However, the complexity is production environment where different adapters are needed.

When launching Ember server in production, services are provided via a bridge:// scheme where the native iOS app is managing transport layer and data models.

```
ember server --environment=production
```

This configuration would extend the base [Adapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html) for production:

```
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
    /* ... */
});
export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

How can multiple adapters be used in an Ember app?  How is the adapter swapped in the App, or perhaps the store from the route would define a different adapter?

Comment: You can override your custom application adapter on a per-model basis, as described here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html Any chance you could write out some pseudo code in the application adapter that describes what you want your adapters to do in dev and then in production? Someone here can probably shape that into working or almost-working code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could provide a global application adapter that will be aware of your environment and export the best suited adapter depending on the current environment (same thing for your serializer if needed):

```
+-- app
|   |-- adapters
|   |   `-- application.js
|   |   `-- custom-adapter.js
|   |-- ...
|   | 
|   |-- serializers
|       `-- application.js
|       `-- custom-serializer.js
```

*application.js:*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from '../config/environment';
import CustomAdapter from './custom-adapter';

var adapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

if (config.environment === 'production') {
    adapter = CustomAdapter;
}

export default adapter;
```

*custom-adapter.js*:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

var adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    // your custom RESTAdapter
});

export default adapter;
```

Hope it will help

Comment: So there can only be one adapter at a time? Why would adapters have their own folders in the structure? Do you need adapters for each resource, or just for the app?