# Using ENV values in ember-cli app during build

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to set my RESTAdapter host based on the build environment.

I assume the value can be stored in `config/environment.js` like this:

```js
if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV.API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:8080';
}

if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.API_ENDPOINT = 'http://api.myserver.com';
}
```

But I am unsure how to insert the information into `adapter/application.js` during the build process.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You define the setting like this in your `config/environment.js`:

```
  // snip
  APP: {
    // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
    // when it is created
    API_HOST: 'http://192.168.1.37:3000' // default setting
  }
};

if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
  ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://192.168.1.37:3000'; // override
}
```

You can then use the setting in other files like this:

```
// app/adapters/application.js:
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   host: window.MyAppENV.APP.API_HOST
});
```

Replace `MyApp` with your application.

You switch to a build environment with the `ember --environment` option:

```
ember serve --environment production
```

or

```
ember build --environment development
```

I've not seen yet whether there is a way to provide the value dynamically, but you can provide as many environments as you want of course.

Update: Adding for completeness, and as per Weston's comment, [Environments](http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments) documents this functionality.

Comment: What you have is exactly what I needed. Dynamically may have been misleading, I meant picking the environment during build.

Comment: Now that I know what to ask I found the documentation on [Environments](http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments)

Comment: Does this solution still work for ember
version: 0.1.0
node: 0.10.28
npm: 1.5.0-alpha-4

Comment: @Millisami I've updated the answer above for the current mechanism. It changed with 0.0.47

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902918/retain-fixtures-with-multiple-adapters-per-ember-environment?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, but when I reference window.EmberENV.APP.API_HOST, I get the error 'Cannot read property 'API_HOST' of undefined'. window.EmberENV is defined, but window.EmberENV.APP is undefined. What am I missing here?