# Environment-based host in Ember CLI app

Tags: ember-cli

I'm trying to configure the adapter in my Ember CLI app to use a different host based on the environment. In dev, I want it to be the default current host (letting me customize it via the `--proxy` option, but in production I know it will be `http://some.url`.

I tried importing my `ENV` into my application adapter:

```
// adapters/application.js
import DS from "ember-data";
import ENV from "../../config/environment";

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.host
});
```

but I'm getting an error that `tmp/tree_merger../config/environment.js` doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ENV values in ember-cli app during build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188263/using-env-values-in-ember-cli-app-during-build)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are pretty close.  You should only going up one step in the directory tree (when you are in a route, controller, etc you need to go up two).

```
// adapters/application.js
import DS from "ember-data";
import ENV from "../config/environment";

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.host
});
```

The documentation is [here](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#Environments).

Note you probably shouldn't be defining your own variables directly on ENV.  Use ENV.APP in `config/environment.js`

```
var ENV = {
  ...
  APP: {
    // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
    // when it is created
    host: 'some_host'
  }
};
```

And access it the same way

```
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.APP.host
});
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, I noticed this after the update that let you `import` the ENV but forgot to change this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
// adapters/application.js
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: window.MyAppENV.host
});
```

though I'm not sure if it's the best method.