# Ember isn't looking for my API

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

So I'm running an `Ember-CLI` and `Rails 5` API-only app. It works fine in development when I use the `--proxy http://localhost:3000` flag, but now I am trying to deploy to `Heroku`.

I have two sides: `recipme-ember` and `recipme-rails`. Feel free to explore the repos:

- amclelland/fancy_recipme_frontend
- amclelland/fancy_recipme

So after some struggling I have both sides deployed, but the `Ember`app refuses to talk to the Rails app.

When I try to go to the `Meal` index I see this in the `Heroku` logs:

> "GET /meals HTTP/1.1" 200 711 "http://recipme-ember.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/50.0.2661.102 Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"

Looks like the `Ember` app is trying to get the `/meals` data from itself.

I have set API_URL env var for my `Ember` app to the `Rails` `Heroku` URL. Not sure if there's something else I need to set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the host property for your adapter:

```
// adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://yourapi.herokuapp.com',
});
```

If you need different hosts for development and production, you can use your config file to change it like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248529/environment-based-host-in-ember-cli-app).